# Angular 2 : ng2-slim-loading-bar : Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: '0'. Current value: '1'

Tags: angular, angular2-http

I use ng2-slim-loading-bar within a Http service wrapper as explained here : [Angular2 - Loading indicator for Http service](https://fewald.net/development/typescipt/angular2/2016/08/29/angular2-http.html)

Sometimes, an exception is raised after starting the loading bar :

```
Exception raised : zone.js:140 Uncaught Error: Error in ./SlimLoadingBarComponent 
class SlimLoadingBarComponent - inline template:3:32 caused by: 
Expression has changed after it was checked.
Previous value: '0'. Current value: '1'.
```

It is not in each case and I really don't know what can trigger this error.

I have to add that as said [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6005) I do not have the problem when is enable Prod Mode...

But in dev mode (local dev), I get this errors.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Angular version? Slim bar version?

Comment: This is probably too old and fixed, I voted to close.